# node log - node.validator: fetching protocol PtEdo

Tags: node, protocol, error

Seeing the following warning in the node log
node.validator: fetching protocol PtEdoTezd3RHSC31mpxxo1npxFjoWWcFgQtxapi51Z8TLu6v6Uq

node running PsDELPH1

what's the issue? thx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your node is incorrectly trying to fetch the next protocol version in preparation for acceptance. Think of it like a forward caching, but the protocol has not passed all stages of voting. You can safely ignore the messages.